# What is the Oracle version used for Rails 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3p551?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I am trying to run an rails 2.3.2 application. For this I installed Ruby 1.9.3p551 using RVM. This application is developed with Oracle as database.
I think I have to install Oracle client and server before installing ruby-oci8 and active_record-oracle_enhanced-adapter.
Please tell me which Oracle version(8/9/10/..) can be installed for this Ruby / Rails versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use any of the version, but preferably 10g and up for installing ruby-oci8.